# Having project in Android Studio with 2 modules defining launcher activity cause wrong activity to be launched on app start

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

I have `Android Studio` project with 2 modules:

1. `app`
2. `library`

Both of them have manifest files with launcher activities, `intent-filter` decalred like this:

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

So when I run application these manifests are merged and launcher activity from `library` module get launched while I need launcher activity from `app` being launched.

Of caurse I can simply remove launcher `intent-filter` declaration from `library` but how can I do this using manifest merger?